# How to redirect after a delete with Symfony and js

Tags: javascript, symfony

I am trying to **refresh** the page with **js**, after a *delete* , but I can not find the mistake.  I am working with **Symfony 4.**

If someone can see where my mistake is it would be really great. :)

This is my **Controller** :

```
 /// SUPPRIMER UNE VIDEO ///

/**
 * @Route("/supprimerVideo/{id}", name="deleteVideo")
 * @Method({"DELETE"})
 * @param Request $request
 * @param $id
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
 */
public function deleteVideo(Request $request, $id){

    $mediaVideo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(MediaVideo::class)->find($id);

    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entityManager->remove($mediaVideo);
    $entityManager->flush();

    $response = new Response();
    $response->send();
}}
```

This is my **js** file :

```js
const videos = document.getElementById('videos');

if (videos){
    videos.addEventListener('click', e => {
        if(e.target.className === 'btn btn-danger delete-item'){
        if (confirm('Es-tu sur de vouloir supprimer ?')) {
            const id = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
            fetch('/supprimerVideo/${id}', {
                method: 'DELETE'
            }).then(res => window.location.reload());
        }
    }
    });
}
```

This is my **twig** file :

```html
<div class="col-12" id="videos">
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger delete-item" data-id="{{video.id}}">Delete</a>
</div>
```

And I added the *script* in *the base.html.twig* too .

Comment: Assuming this is a Symfony app then you would never call $response->send yourself.  The framework takes care of it.  Instead you would do something like return new RedirectResponse($url); or even return $this->redirect($url);  This is the sort of thing that a quick search for "symfony redirect" would resolve.  And needless to say, though I'll say it anyways, you need to redirect to someplace.

Comment: I took this from a tutorial on YouTube and it works with his code, but  in the mine, it is even not deleting the video actually.. but it's ok, thank you for the time that you took for it :) About the  " redirectResponse " I can't find it, but I found the " $this-redirect" , they say it is for external url address, this is not my case I think..

Comment: That is fine.  Normally I would expect an action like you posted would return a bit of json indicating a successful delete.  It is curious why the return annotations indicate a RedirectResponse is returned when in fact nothing is returned.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Replace quotes in `fetch('/supprimerVideo/${id}', {` with backticks:

```
const id = 123;
console.log('/supprimerVideo/${id}')
/supprimerVideo/${id}
console.log(`/supprimerVideo/${id}`)
/supprimerVideo/123
```

You are using Template literals ${} that are not replaced with actual id value. Inspect your request in debug toolbar to see if you are really calling correct url in your symfony application.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer